# CONCAT doesn't recognize built in function

Tags: concatenation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdqbE.png)

Hi goodevening i just want to ask, how to fix this. the concat says that it doesn't recognize builtin function.

Comment: CONCAT was introduced in SQL Server 2012. Which version do you use?

Comment: Thank for your response. I use 2019.

Comment: Can you try avoid CONCAT just by using the `+` operator. Like this: `username + ' is created'`.

Comment: Thank you again it works. God Bless.

Comment: glad to hear it works. I have posted it as an answer as it might be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Yes of course. That's cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try avoid `CONCAT` just by using the `+` operator.

Syntax fill be following, instead of:

```
CONCAT(username, ' ', 'is created')
```

use

```
username + ' is created'
```